# Limit of monotone non-decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ with $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ and $i:=\inf E, s:=\sup E$ are limit points of $E$.

***Theorem:*** Suppose that $f:E\to \mathbb{R}$ is nondecreasing on $E$.

i) Then  $\lim \limits_{x\to s} f(x)$ exists if and only if $f(x)$ is bounded above.

ii) Then $\lim \limits_{x\to i} f(x)$ exists if and only if $f(x)$ is bounded below.

*Proof:* $\Rightarrow$ Suppose that $s\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to s} f(x)=A$. Then $\exists \delta>0$ $\forall x\in E(0<|x-s|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-A|<1)$.

We consider two cases: If $s\in E$ then for any $t\in E$ it follows that $t\leq s$ and $f(t)\leq f(s)$. So our function is bounded above by $f(s)$.

Suppose $s\notin E$. Then take any $t\in E$. If $0<|t-s|<\delta$ then $f(t)<A+1$. But if $|t-s|\geq \delta$ then $t\leq s-\delta$ and since $s\in E'$ then $\exists \xi \in E$ and $\xi\in(s-\delta,s)$. So $f(t)\leq f(\xi)<A+1.$

So in each case $f(x)$ is bounded above.

What if $s=+\infty$. Then $\lim \limits_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=A$ then $\exists\delta>0$  $\forall x\in E (x>\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-A|<1).$

Take any $t\in E$. If $t>\delta$ then $f(t)<A+1.$ But if $t\leq \delta$ then $\exists x_0\in E, x_0>\delta$ then $f(t)\leq f(x_0)<A+1$.

Is my reasoning logically correct?

Comment: Your proof looks fine.

Comment: @copper.hat, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I thought I had a shorter proof but it ended up being longer.